# Is it possible to mutate component state outside React app?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

For a simple React app:

```
// App.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('hello'); // state
  return <div>{name}</div>;
};
export default App;

// main.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

window.changeNameTo = ? // a method
```

Then in console, I can run `changeNameTo('world')` to mutate the state (not just html or DOM), is this possible?

**Update**

Actually I have two React apps (legacy, also not small) mounting on different divs on same page, then there is a requirement that clicking on button in one app can trigger a change on another one. Since it is not worthy of refactoring and consolidating them for a small requirement, a hack solution is acceptable and well preferred. From my perspective, I would write a delegate client (maybe use `window` as intermediate place) to bridge the communication.

Comment: you probably could, but this already seems like an incredibly bad idea

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu just for hack or debug use, how can I write the method?

Comment: You don't, what you do instead is explain what you're trying to do, because you thought this would get you there, and now you're asking about how to do this, instead of asking how to do the thing you actually set out to do. So: what are you _really_ trying to do?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Actually I have two React apps (legacy, also not small) mounting on different divs on same page, then there is a requirement that I click one button in one app to trigger a change on another one. Avoiding making changes to consolidating them, I would write a delegate client (maybe use `window` as intermediate place) to bridge the communication, so I would first try to write a PoC for evaluation.

Comment: Please update your post with that information, so that everyone knows that, not just people digging through comments =) (every time someone asks you a question in a comment, that's typically the sign your post was missing details that should be put in)

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can, but you should be really careful when doing such a thing.
Take a look for an example here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-gareth-9owzq?file=/src/index.js

Try using the console and invoke `ChangeName("[YourWantedStr]");`

Just to be clear- your question was if it's possible.
Yes it is.
But you shouldn't do such a thing, if you need to mutate your state in such a way you probably used bad architecture while building your app.

Answer (score 0):

**For debugging only** - When you need a function outside a component's, you can wrap it in an arrow function and `console.log()` it. In Chrome you can then right click the function at the console, and select "Store as global variable", and it will be saved as `tempX` (1 if it's the 1st). Now you can use it from the console.

This is better than adding functions to the `window` object, since linters will warn you about the `console.log()` when building for production.

In the snippet, you'll have to select the correct iframe first (click `top` in chrome).

```js
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('hello'); // state
  
  console.log((...args) => setName(...args));
  
  return <div>{name}</div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tested this, but I think you can assign `setName` function to a property on window object. And call as `window.setName` anywhere in the code